# A method of totaling data every hour from data in which plural datetimes are stored

Tags: python, pandas

There is data that stores datetime and score as follows.

```
data = [
{'datetime': '2016-07-16 01:00:00+00:00', 'score': 100},
{'datetime': '2016-07-16 01:00:00+00:00', 'score': 314},
{'datetime': '2016-07-16 01:00:00+00:00', 'score': 1312},
{'datetime': '2016-07-16 01:30:00+00:00', 'score': 135},
{'datetime': '2016-07-16 01:30:00+00:00', 'score': 594},
{'datetime': '2016-07-16 01:30:00+00:00', 'score': 542},
{'datetime': '2016-07-16 02:00:00+00:00', 'score': 1431},
{'datetime': '2016-07-16 02:00:00+00:00', 'score': 431},
{'datetime': '2016-07-16 02:00:00+00:00', 'score': 89},
{'datetime': '2016-07-16 02:30:00+00:00', 'score': 1340},
{'datetime': '2016-07-16 02:30:00+00:00', 'score': 433},
{'datetime': '2016-07-16 02:30:00+00:00', 'score': 594},
{'datetime': '2016-07-17 01:00:00+00:00', 'score': 100},
{'datetime': '2016-07-17 01:00:00+00:00', 'score': 594},
{'datetime': '2016-07-17 01:00:00+00:00', 'score': 100},
{'datetime': '2016-07-17 01:30:00+00:00', 'score': 594},
{'datetime': '2016-07-17 01:30:00+00:00', 'score': 100},
{'datetime': '2016-07-17 01:30:00+00:00', 'score': 600},
{'datetime': '2016-07-17 02:00:00+00:00', 'score': 500},
{'datetime': '2016-07-17 02:00:00+00:00', 'score': 400},
{'datetime': '2016-07-17 02:00:00+00:00', 'score': 300},
{'datetime': '2016-07-17 02:30:00+00:00', 'score': 400},
{'datetime': '2016-07-17 02:30:00+00:00', 'score': 900},
{'datetime': '2016-07-17 02:30:00+00:00', 'score': 1100},
{'datetime': '2016-07-18 01:00:00+00:00', 'score': 140},
{'datetime': '2016-07-18 01:00:00+00:00', 'score': 150},
{'datetime': '2016-07-18 01:00:00+00:00', 'score': 160},
{'datetime': '2016-07-18 01:30:00+00:00', 'score': 170},
{'datetime': '2016-07-18 01:30:00+00:00', 'score': 180},
{'datetime': '2016-07-18 01:30:00+00:00', 'score': 190},
{'datetime': '2016-07-18 02:00:00+00:00', 'score': 200},
{'datetime': '2016-07-18 02:00:00+00:00', 'score': 120},
{'datetime': '2016-07-18 02:00:00+00:00', 'score': 190},
{'datetime': '2016-07-18 02:30:00+00:00', 'score': 500},
{'datetime': '2016-07-18 02:30:00+00:00', 'score': 600},
{'datetime': '2016-07-18 02:30:00+00:00', 'score': 700},
]
```

I want to compile the average score for each hour against this data.
The summary result assumes the following data. (score value is sample)

```
summary = [
{'hour': '01:00', 'average_score': 100},
{'hour': '02:00', 'average_score': 800}
]
```

Is there any good way to compile like this?
I think that it is good to use pandas, but I can not think of concrete code.
I would like to tell you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**pandas solution**:

```
#create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#convert to datetimes
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
#groupby by hours and aggregate mean
df = (df.groupby(df['datetime'].dt.strftime('%H:00').rename('hour'))['score']
       .mean()
       .reset_index(name='average_score'))
print (df)
    hour  average_score
0  01:00     337.500000
1  02:00     568.222222

#convert to list of dicionaries
summary = df.to_dict(orient='records')
print (summary)
[{'hour': '01:00', 'average_score': 337.5}, 
 {'hour': '02:00', 'average_score': 568.2222222222222}]
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is with a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) of lists using the 2 digit hour as a key, which can be extracted directly from fixed positions in the datetime strings. Accumulate the scores grouped by the hour into a list in the defaultdict, then calculate the averages after all items have been grouped.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from statistics import mean

d = defaultdict(list)

for item in data:
    hour = item['datetime'][11:13]
    d[hour].append(item['score'])

summary = [{'hour': '{}:00'.format(hour), 'average_score': mean(d[hour])} for hour in d]

from pprint import pprint
pprint(summary)
```

Output:

```
[{'average_score': 337.5, 'hour': '01:00'},
 {'average_score': 568.2222222222222, 'hour': '02:00'}]
```